# can't list my own Youtube videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get a list of the videos I've posted in YouTube

When using the explorer:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

it generated following query

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

and the following (400) response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.search",
    "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
    "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done making 2 requests to the Youtube v3 API:

1. The first request you need to make for this is to get the id of your
   uploaded videos playlist:

   This is a GET request to url:

   ```
   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels"
   ```

   with headers:

   ```
   "Content-type": "application/json",
   "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % {YOUR ACCESS TOKEN}
   ```

   and parameters:

   ```
   "part": "contentDetails",
   "mine": "true",
   "key": {YOUR APPLICATION KEY}
   ```

   From the response you want to access:

   response_body["items"][0][contentDetails][relatedPlaylists][uploads]
2. The second request is to get all the videos you have in
   your uploads playlist.

   To get this start with a GET request to URL:

   ```
   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems"
   ```

   sending headers:

   ```
   "Content-type": "application/json",
   "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % {YOUR AUTH TOKEN}
   ```

   and parameters:

   ```
   "part": "snippet", {Add other "parts" here like stats if you want that info.}
   "maxResults": {MORE THAN 50? PAGINATION IS NEEDED / SEE BELOW},
   "playlistId": {FROM ABOVE},
   "key": {YOUR API KEY}
   ```

   The response will have your list of videos and their associated information.

   if (while) the response has response_body["nextPageToken"] in it, you need to resend the request with parameter "pageToken": {NEXT PAGE TOKEN} to get the rest of your paginated results.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the `forMine` parameter, you also have to set the `type` parameter to video so that the API knows what kinds of resources to return.

Comment: Also worth noting: it appears you need to have actually created your own channel via [https://www.youtube.com/create_channel](https://www.youtube.com/create_channel) otherwise you get 404 errors when using forMine=true&type=video